# Does anyone know a better solution to the below dice problem?

Tags: java

There are a number of dice, and the input array contains the number on the dice's face up. Dice is 6 faced. Calculate the total number of minimum rotations of dice, to make all faces the same. 1 will require only one rotation to have 2, 3, 4 and 5 face up, but would require minimum two rotations to make it the face 6, as 6 is the opposite side of 1. The opposite side of 2 is 5 and 3 is 4.

I have come up with **a solution**, but I believe there should be a better solution.

**For example:**

1. `A = {1,1,6}`, Answer = 2. Rotate 6 two times to get 1.
2. `A = {1,2,3}`, Answer = 2. Rotate 1 and 2 and make them 3.
3. `A = {1,6,2,3}`, Answer = 3. Rotate 1, 6 and 3 to make them all 2.

   ```
   import java.util.*;

   public class DiceProblem {
       public static void main(String args[]){
       int[] A = {3,4,1,2,4,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,6,2,4,1,5,2};
       Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
       int rotation = 0;
       int diceCount;
       int maxDiceNumber = A[0];
       int OppositeOfMaxDiceNumber;
       int max = 1;

       for(int i = 1; i <= 6 ; i++){
           diceCount = 0;
           for (int value : A) {
               if(i == value){
                   diceCount++;
               }
           }
           countMap.put(i, diceCount);
           if(diceCount > max){
               max = diceCount;
               maxDiceNumber = i;
           }
       }

       if(max == 1){
           if(countMap.get(1).equals(countMap.get(6)) && countMap.get(1) != 0 && countMap.get(2) != 0){
               maxDiceNumber = 2;
           }else if(countMap.get(2).equals(countMap.get(5))  && countMap.get(2) != 0 && countMap.get(3) != 0){
               maxDiceNumber = 3;
           }else if(countMap.get(3).equals(countMap.get(4)) && countMap.get(1) != 0){
               maxDiceNumber = 1;
           }else if(countMap.get(2) != 0){
               maxDiceNumber = 2;
           }else if(countMap.get(5) != 0){
               maxDiceNumber = 5;
           }else if(countMap.get(6) != 0){
               maxDiceNumber = 6;
           }
       }

       System.out.println("Max Dice Number: "+ maxDiceNumber);
       OppositeOfMaxDiceNumber = createOpposite(maxDiceNumber);
       System.out.println("Opposite Dice Number: "+ OppositeOfMaxDiceNumber);

       Iterator it2 = countMap.entrySet().iterator();
       while (it2.hasNext()) {
           Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it2.next();
           System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
           if((int)(pair.getValue()) > 0 && (int)(pair.getKey()) != maxDiceNumber){
               if((int)(pair.getKey()) == OppositeOfMaxDiceNumber){
                   rotation = rotation + (2  * (int)(pair.getValue()));
               }else {
                   rotation = rotation + ((int)(pair.getValue()));
               }
           }

           it2.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
       }
       System.out.println("Number of Minimum Rotations: "+ rotation);

   }
   private static int createOpposite(int key){
       switch (key) {
           case 1:
               return 6;
           case 2:
               return 5;
           case 3:
               return 4;
           case 4:
               return 3;
           case 5:
               return 2;
           case 6:
               return 1;
       }
       return 0;
   }}
   ```

Comment: So, to clarify: `A` is the top face of various dice, a face value of 1 requires one rotation (why wouldn't this be zero?), a face value of 2-5 requires one rotation, a face value of 6 requires two rotations, and the end goal is to print the number of rotations required for all dice to show one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already have a working solution. If you are looking for help reviewing your code in order to improve it, you should post the question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done in O(n) by counting the occurrence of each side.

Comment: @daniu, you're right about counting the occurrences, but that doesn't give you O(n). It does better than that.  Without it, you're at O(n), because the outer loop is always 6 iterations anyway.  That optimization takes you to somewhere between O(n) and O(1). Once you do that original tally, the alg consists of a finite number of steps, 36, regardless of the number of dice in the original list, so the latter part is O(1).  The whole thing is not O(1) though, because since the rest of the alg is so simple, taking that original tally is a meaningful amount of the work. (see comments on my answer)

Comment: @Steve I might be mistaken, but counting the occurences means iterating the list once, hence O(n)? I'm writing a solution now.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class DiceProblem {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int[] A = {3,4,1,2,4,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,6,2,4,1,5,2};
        int flip_count;
        int min_flip_count = 9999999;

        for (int value : A) {
            flip_count = 0;
            for (int i : A) {
                if (value == i) {
                    flip_count += 0;
                } else if (value + i == 7) {
                    flip_count += 2;
                } else {
                    flip_count += 1;
                }
            }
            if (flip_count < min_flip_count) {
                min_flip_count = flip_count;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Minimum Flip Count:" + min_flip_count);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can optimize this to O(n) because we know that the only possible dice numbers are 1,2,3,..6. So the outer for loop can be changed to `for (int i = 1; i <=6; i ++)`.

Answer (score 2):

I thought for a while to try to come up with a better solution than brute-force; that is, without just considering what it would take to get all dice to each of the  6 potential positions.  I bet there's some smart way to do that, but I couldn't come up with it.

So I wrote my own version of the brute-force solution seeking to simplify your code quite a bit.  A first observation is that the two sides of a dice always add up to 7, so given a die value, the opposite is always found by subtracting that value from 7.  No need for a bunch of if statements, or a lookup, or anything.  A simple subtraction gets that done. And if you want to see if two positions are opposites, just see if they add up to 7.

Then I just wrote code do the most direct thing...consider each die position, tally the number of flips to get all the dice to that position, and keep track of the minimum flip position as we go along.

UPDATE: One optimization that can be done is to create a count of dies at each position just once.  Then we don't have to process each die every time through our outer loop, but rather process the counts of the positions of each die.  I updated the first version of my code I posted previously to use this optimization.  This means you'll have 6 * 6 = 36 pairs of positions to consider no matter how many dice are in your list.

With all this, here's the code I came up with:

```
public class DiceProblem {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] A = {3,4,1,2,4,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,6,2,4,1,5,2};

        // Figure out how many dice we have in each position
        int[] pos_counts = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        for (int start_pos : A)
            pos_counts[start_pos] += 1;

        // Initilize our accumulators for minimum flips and which position that was
        int min_flips = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int min_flip_pos = 0;

        // Consider each of the 6 dice positions...
        for (int position = 1 ; position <= 6 ; position++) {

            // initialize the number of flips
            int flips = 0;

            // Go through all the dice starting positions and tally up the flips necessary to get all dice to the position
            // we are considering
            for (int start_pos = 1 ;  start_pos <= 6 ; start_pos++) {
                if (start_pos + position == 7)  // opposite sides of a dice always add up to 7
                    flips += 2 * pos_counts[start_pos];
                else if (start_pos != position)
                    flips += pos_counts[start_pos];
            }

            // If this is a smaller number of flips than we've seen before, record it as the new best choice
            if (flips < min_flips) {
                min_flips = flips;
                min_flip_pos = position;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("%d flips to die position %d", min_flips, min_flip_pos));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
15 flips to die position 2
```

which is the same answer your code came up with.

Comment: Being curious, thanks to @daniu's comments, about how the algorithm behaves in execution time as you make the dice list longer, I did some timing tests.  I did 100,000 iterations.  On the OPs list of 18 dice, this takes 7 milliseconds.  On a list of 540 dice, this, it takes 42 millis.  So the alg really is significantly better than O(n).  It's not O(1) only because performing the optimization of taking the initial tally takes a significant amount of time considering how simple and reduced the rest of the algorithm is.  As the latter part of the alg becomes more complex, we'd approach O(1).

Answer (score 0):

For a good solution, think about how many turns it takes for each side.

- For dice with this side up already, it takes 0 turns.
- For dice with the opposite side up (eg 3 for 4), it takes 2 turns.
- For all other dice, it takes 1 turn.

You can use this to write a function like this:

```
int turnsForSide(int side, Map<Integer, Long> sideCount);
```

`side` is the side you're looking for; the `Map<Integer, Long> sideCount`'s key indicates the die side, and the value the amount of dice you have with that side.

Now all you have to do is to get the count for each side; that's rather trivial. Write a function like this:

```
Map<Integer, Long> getSideCounts(int[] sidesUp);
```

If you have those two functions, you can just iterate the map and find the side with the minimum value.

```
int[] A = {3,4,1,2,4,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,6,2,4,1,5,2};
Map<Integer, Long> counts = getSideCounts(A);
Map<Integer,Integer> turns = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    turns.put(i, turnsForSide(i, counts));
}
// you could also retain the minimum in the loop above to avoid another iteration
turns.entrySet().stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .map(entry -> String.format("minimum amount: %d for side %d", entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()))
        .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

This is rather effective since you only need to iterate the original array once, then the map with the side which is a fixed amount of iterations (6), so overall this should be O(n) if I remember complexity theory correctly.

I do have the code for the functions, but since it seems to be homework, I think it'd help more if you try to write it first.